# Could not run nginx with gunicorn, getting permission denied error while connecting to upstream

Tags: django, nginx, centos

I have hosted django with nginx and gunicorn. I am getting following error.

```
# 1 connect() to 127.0.0.1:8001 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 106.77.61.123, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/favicon.ico", host: "<domainname>
```

**[Same configuration is working on my local centos machine]**

But on VPS hosted environment (vps):

I am using centos-7 with user name "ftpuser1" (username in nginx.conf is "ftpuser1").

I am running nginx using user "ftpuser1"

owner of /var/cache/nginx is "ftpuser1" with 777 permissions recursively

owner of source code path is also "ftpuser1" with 777 permissions recursively

here is my /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.config config file content:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /home/ftpuser1/donation/templates;
        index  home.html;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #} }
```

Can anyone help me in this ?

Comment: check if anything else is running on that port with `netstat -tulpn | grep 8001`

Answer (score 0):

This error message means, you dont have read + write permission to the root folder that serves "favicon.ico", if your in linux environment;

try this command: `sudo chmod 775 /<foldername>`

dont forget the `sudo` at the begining of your command.

then after you applied the permission try to restart your *nginx server

Comment: I change permissions of source code to 777 recursively and owner is  ftpuser1. I restarted nginx but still problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Fix the the closing bracket "}" at the end of the config (is not the problem)
2. Try putting "user ftpuser1;" at the top of the config before "server {..}"

Comment: 1. Its already close, while copy pasting other editior its come to above one line, mistakenly it shows comment, its not commented, It close properly. 2. in nginx.conf user ftpuse1 already there

Comment: then maybe the user itself has no permissions when you created it?